# Generated source files giving error of "incompatible type" by using different String object in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android object in which I have used **`java.lang.String`** as the String object. When I build the project, I get following errors in files **`Manifest.java`** and **`BuildConfig.java`** located in directory 
 **app/build/generated/source/r/debug**:

> error: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.wordpress.zeel.silverglitters.String

I tried changing them to java.lang.String and rebuilding the project but got the same outcome. Please help me out.

Comment: Do you have a class named String in your project ?

Comment: We need to see the relevant code to answer this.

Comment: Check your import statements for the `com.wordpress.*` string

Comment: @GokulNathKP Yes. I had a class named String in my project. I renamed it and it worked. Thanks a lot for help!